# PayPal Order Summary not showing consistently

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

My Express Checkout redirect to PayPal using the classic (SOAP) API only sometimes shows the order-summary, even while using the same code with the same temporarily hard-coded parameters.

When I recently first saw the order-summary show, it seemed to have been thanks to my having just started setting PaymentAction to PaymentActionCodeType.ORDER on PaymentDetailsType, rather than only on SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType, but later I stopped seeing the order-summary.  The only change I made to the code in the interim is to ensure PaymentAction is set to PaymentActionCodeType.ORDER also in the PaymentDetailsType used in the DoExpressCheckoutPayment call, which I did as a fix for the problem of the DoAuthorization call failing with "invalid transaction id".

I've seen here a post or two about "forcing" one layout or another, and forcing the order-summary to show, e.g., with "useraction=commit", but that hasn't worked.

So, I'd just like to know what all needs to be true in order for the order-summary to show consistently when using Express Checkout via the classic (SOAP) API.

Comment: Does the design of the page look the same each time, just with or without the details, or does the design of the page actually change quite a bit?  They have been slowly rolling out new EC flow pages, so it's expected that you would see different page styles at some points even with the same exact code.  The new version of the pages still has the summary, but you have to click a little drop down thing to see it.  Maybe that's what you're running into..??

Comment: When what I mean by the order-summary isn't showing, what is available is a little drop-down in the upper right corner, which includes only the bare minimum details (product-name, price, and order-subtotal), even though I'm sending also product-description and quantity; the latter details do show when what I mean by the order-summary is showing; then, there's the whole order-summary view down the lefthand side, and several inputs on the right, e.g., for username/password.  I believe the client I'm doing this work for wants the latter full-detail display always.

Comment: Ok, well again, it sounds like you're just running into the new pages they're introducing.  Unfortunately, you can't adjust that layout on the new pages.  I know PayPal does have a flag where they can force a PayPal account to always use the old pages, however, they're very reluctant to do this for people.  You could always call your account manager and ask, though.